# Unity Vuforia can't make child as an image target to appear

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation, vuforia

I am trying make my prefabs appear at runtime on my imagetarget by following this link 
[vuforia instantiate prefab on imagetarget dynamically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GP9E1.png)

the only difference is that I want to be able to drag some prefabs that I created instead of only one prefab shown in the tutorial.

```
public GameObject[] prefabModels;
```

my problem is even after my imagetarget is detected all my 3d prefabs didn't show up.

this code is attached to my imagetarget object

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Vuforia;

public class ImageTargetMgr : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler {

private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;

public GameObject[] prefabModels;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {                
    mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();

    if (mTrackableBehaviour)
    {
        mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
    }        
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

public void OnTrackableStateChanged(TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus, TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
{
    if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED || newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED || newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
    {
        OnTrackingFound();
    }
    else
    {
        OnTrackingLost();
    }
}

private void OnTrackingLost()
{

}

private void OnTrackingFound()
{
    Debug.Log("Image Target Found!");
    foreach (GameObject o in prefabModels)
    {
        if (o != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Currently instantiated models is " + o.name);

            GameObject myPrefab = Instantiate(o, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

            myPrefab.transform.parent = mTrackableBehaviour.transform;
            myPrefab.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f);
            myPrefab.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
            //o.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1000.0f, 1000.0f, 1000.0f);

            myPrefab.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        }

    }

}
```

here are the log and what shown on hierarchy when running the scene

hope I will get some helps here..cheers

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you assigned any prefabs to prefabModels array?

Comment: Yes...i hv assigned some prefabs

Comment: Does it ever call OnTrackingFound ? and log out "Image Target Found!" and "Currently instantiated models is"?

Comment: It did. OnTackingFound fired but somehow those prefabs didn't appear. Checked the log and printed out both test strings.

Comment: I noticed there is an instance of Glowtab(Clone) as seen on the second pic. However the object didn't seem to be rendered on the image target.

Comment: Looks like it's instantiating the prefab. Can you screenshot the inspector for "Image Target"

Answer (score 0):

The problem finally solved after I added Box Collider component to the prefab object. I have to tweak also some of the transform settings.

Below are the screen captures of the prefab's inspector panel at runtime
[image]

[image]